# ggarrange() function overvrites the color of my boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making two boxplots and want to arrange them beside each other. I have made each of them look like I want when displaying them separately but when I use *ggarrange()* the colors disappear. This is my code for the plots:

```
BOX1_data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", 
                      sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
BOX1_data$Diagnosis <- as.factor(BOX1_data$Diagnosis)
BOX1plot <- ggplot(BOX1_data, aes(x=Diagnosis, y=No.Variants, fill= Diagnosis)) + geom_boxplot() + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("AC\nN=38", "SqCC\nN=15", "SCLC\nN=8", "BL disease\nN=16"))

BOX2_data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", 
                     sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
BOX2_data$Stage <- as.factor(BOX2_data$Stage)
BOX2plot <- ggplot(BOX2_data, aes(x=Stage, y=No.Variants, fill = Stage))    + geom_boxplot(width = 0.4) + 
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") + 
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Stage I-III\nN=24", "Stage IV\nN=37"))
```

To arrange the plots I then write:

```
BOX_list <- list(BOX1plot, BOX2plot)
ggarrange(plotlist = BOX_list, labels = c('A', 'B'), ncol = 2)
```

The easiest way of getting rid of gridlines etc I thought was by using theme_set() and I think that this might be my problem.
My code is:

```
theme_set(theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), 
                    axis.line = element_line(colour = "grey")))
```

I realize that *theme_bw()* overwrites my colors in the boxes. But I have tried removing it, switching it for *theme_transparent()* (this removes all my labels) and neither works. I have searched for a way of just adding a transparency to my boxes in the theme so that my colors will shine through. I am also suspicious that maybe the palette that I chose might give me the same colors in the two plots which I also do not want. To add, if it matters, I have 4 groups in the first plot and 2 in the second.

```
dput(BOX1_data)
structure(list(Diagnosis = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    No.Variants = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    8L, 6L, 22L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 13L, 3L, 
    11L, 19L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 18L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 
    4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 15L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 
    10L, 10L, 12L, 6L, 3L, 12L, 9L, 15L, 10L, 18L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 
    6L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 10L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 0L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-77L), class = "data.frame")
dput(BOX2_data)
structure(list(No.Variants = c(3L, 4L, 6L, 14L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 8L, 6L, 22L, 10L, 6L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 2L, 13L, 
3L, 11L, 19L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 12L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 18L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 
4L, 1L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 10L, 3L, 15L, 9L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 10L, 
10L, 12L, 6L, 3L, 12L, 9L, 15L, 10L, 18L), Stage = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -61L), class = "data.frame")
```

Grateful for any tips!

Comment: Could you please `dput(BOX1_data )` and `dput(BOX2_data )` and paste the result in the question in order to help you!

Comment: I have added dput() in the question. :)

Comment: Hm. As far as I get it your code works fine. No colors are disappearing when using ggarrange. Using ggplot2 3.3.2 and ggpubr 0.4.0.

Comment: Aha! I was using ggplot2 3.3.0... It worked when I reinstalled it to the new version. Thank you! 
Now it is just the problem that I want the palette to continue on the second plot's boxes and not restart so that I will get different colors on all boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out, it seems the OP's issue with `theme_set()` removing the fill colors set in your two plots was solved by updating to a new version of `ggplot2`.  Herein, I have a solution for the second part of OP's question (that was clarified in the comments).  Represented here for convenience:

> Now it is just the problem that I want the palette to continue on the second plot's boxes and not restart so that I will get different colors on all boxes.

In order to do this, one has to realize that there are 4 fill colors for the first plot `BOX1plot`, and 2 fill colors for `BOX2plot`.  For `BOX1plot`, we want the color palette to begin at the first color, but for `BOX2plot`, we want the palette to start on the 5th color sequence in the palette.  There's no way to do this through the `scale_*_brewer()` functions, so the approach here will be to access the Brewer palette from `RcolorBrewer::brewer.pal()`, and then assign where to begin and end in that sequence based on the number of levels of each factor using `scale_fill_manual()` to just set the color values from the extracted Brewer color palette.

You can just "know" that you need to "use colors 1-4" for `BOX1plot` and "use color 5 and 6" for `BOX2plot`; however, it is much more elegant to just calculate this automatically based on the number of levels (in case you want to run this again).  The code below does this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(RColorBrewer)

# ... read in your data as before

# create factors (as OP did before)
BOX1_data$Diagnosis <- as.factor(BOX1_data$Diagnosis)
BOX2_data$Stage <- as.factor(BOX2_data$Stage)

# make color palette based on Brewer "Dark2" palette
lev_diag <- length(levels(BOX1_data$Diagnosis))
lev_stage <- length(levels(BOX2_data$Stage))
lev_total <- lev_diag + lev_stage
my_colors <- brewer.pal(lev_total, "Dark2")

BOX1plot <- ggplot(BOX1_data, aes(x=Diagnosis, y=No.Variants, fill= Diagnosis)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=my_colors[1:lev_diag]) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("AC\nN=38", "SqCC\nN=15", "SCLC\nN=8", "BL disease\nN=16"))

BOX2plot <- ggplot(BOX2_data, aes(x=Stage, y=No.Variants, fill = Stage))    + geom_boxplot(width = 0.4) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = my_colors[(lev_diag+1):lev_total]) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Stage I-III\nN=24", "Stage IV\nN=37"))

BOX_list <- list(BOX1plot, BOX2plot)
ggarrange(plotlist = BOX_list, labels = c('A', 'B'), ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was really neat and solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you have issues with `ggarrange()` I would suggest next approach using `patchwork`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

#Data format
BOX1_data$Diagnosis <- as.factor(BOX1_data$Diagnosis)
#Plot 1
BOX1plot <- ggplot(BOX1_data, aes(x=Diagnosis, y=No.Variants, fill= Diagnosis)) + geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("AC\nN=38", "SqCC\nN=15", "SCLC\nN=8", "BL disease\nN=16"))
#Data format
BOX2_data$Stage <- as.factor(BOX2_data$Stage)
#Plot 2
BOX2plot <- ggplot(BOX2_data, aes(x=Stage, y=No.Variants, fill = Stage))    + geom_boxplot(width = 0.4) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Stage I-III\nN=24", "Stage IV\nN=37"))

#Arrange plots
BOX1plot+BOX2plot+plot_annotation(tag_levels = 'A')
```

The output:

[image]